# How can install sqlite-ruby on linux when sqlite3 is not in /usr/local?

Tags: ruby, linux, sqlite, installation

I am trying to install sqlite3 and sqlite-ruby (ruby 1.8.6) on a linux box where I do not have root.

I downloaded the sqlite3 source, binaries, and shared library and placed them all in a directory called sqlite3

I then try to install sqlite-ruby using

```
gem install sqlite-ruby --with-sqlite-dir=the_path_sqlite/sqlite3
```

but I keep getting the error...

```
checking for main() in -lsqlite... no
checking for sqlite.h... no
*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of
necessary libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more
details.  You may need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
 --with-opt-dir
 --without-opt-dir
 --with-opt-include
 --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
 --with-opt-lib
 --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
 --with-make-prog
 --without-make-prog
 --srcdir=.
 --curdir
 --ruby=/data/scratch/bettbra/common/packages/ruby-1.8.6/bin/ruby
 --with-sqlite-dir
 --with-sqlite-include
 --without-sqlite-include=${sqlite-dir}/include
 --with-sqlite-lib
 --without-sqlite-lib=${sqlite-dir}/lib
 --with-sqlitelib
 --without-sqlitelib
```

Comment: Please reformat your answer using the "code" button. Also post the contents of "mkmf.log".

Answer (score 2):

You specify where the development files (headers & lib) are using the following syntax:

```
gem install sqlite3 -- --with-sqlite3-include=$HOME/include --with-sqlite3-lib=$HOME/lib
```

Notice the -- that mark the end of `gem` options. After them, the options are passed to the extension compiling process.

However, I second Reuben's advice; you should really consider using RVM. It is a blessing for this kind of situations AND to smooth your migration to Ruby 1.9.

Answer (score 1):

i'm using ubuntu (debain type linux). i managed to resolve it the following way:

sudo apt-get install sqlite3 libsqlite3-dev
sudo gem install sqlite3-ruby

Comment: Charles did say he does not have root access

Comment: I am no expert, but from my experience - if you do not have root access on Linux you really cant do much. Gota get sudo password.

Comment: You can certainly do a lot of things — including installing things under your home directory — without root *or* sudo access. I have run into very little software that did not support a different PREFIX or something similar.

Answer (score 1):

Can you install RVM (Ruby Version Manager) ?

https://rvm.io/rvm/install/

With RVM you install gems etc. as a user *without* sudo/root privileges.